# Find $C$ if $B(B-C)=23$. $B$ and $C$ are positive integers.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

I don't know how to tackle the problem. I tried to factor the equation and use systems of equations but it still does not work. Please give a good proof.

Answer (score 3):

As $B>0, B-C$ must be positive $\implies B>C$

As $C>0, B$ must be $>B-C$

Again as $23$ is prime,$23=23\cdot1$

So, $B=23,B-C=1$

Comment: Oh wow. I didn't realise that 23 X 1=23. It was common sense.

Answer (score 3):

The equation says two integers multiply to $23$. So, how can that happen?

Comment: Well 23 into 1 is 23.

Comment: this answer is full of winz.

Comment: I would say $1$ into $23$ is $23$, but apparently customs differ. Anyway, that tells you $1\times23=23$. Are there any other possibilities? Once you have all the possibilities, you have all the possible values of $B$, right?